# Upload data into a locally hosted database in asp - login error

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-identity, identity

run into a bit of a problem when trying to create my website.

I apologise for the length of this post, i'm just so stumped as to what to do to resolve this, i've spent over 5 hours trying to fix it already

I am trying to record a (Logged in) users score from a multiple choice test into a table i have created in the same database that the users info is stored. I am using asp.net identity to create the users (Adapted from the default template) and cant seem to get it to work.

I have two tables, one was created on its own and one that i created manually.

The first table(dbo.AspNetUsers) hold user data like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [Email]                NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed]       BIT            NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] BIT            NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled]     BIT            NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEndDateUtc]    DATETIME       NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled]       BIT            NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [UserName]             NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    [Dateofbirth]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Firstname]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Surname]              NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([UserName] ASC);
```

The second (dbo.AspNetUserTestScores) is configured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserTestScores] (
    [Id]                                                  NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [MomentsAndEnergyTestScore]                           NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [MotionInACircleTestScore]                            NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [UniversalGravtationTestScore]                        NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [CapacitanceTestScore]                                NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [ElectricFieldsTestScore]                             NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [MagneticFieldsTestScore]                             NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [ElectronsAndNucleiTestScore]                         NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [ParticlePhysicsTestScore]                            NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [NuclearDecayTestScore]                               NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [GasLawsAndKineticTheoryTestScore]                    NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [InternalEnergyAbsoluteZeroAndChangeOfStateTestScore] NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [SpecificHeatCapacityTestScore]                       NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [AstrophysicsTestScore]                               NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [CosmologyTestScore]                                  NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [OscillationsTestScore]                               NVARCHAR (256) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
);
```

I am trying to save a score for the user logged in into a column in the second table using the id of the user that is logged in and the score that they get from the test however the code that i am using just isnt working at all.

Here is the code for the upload into the table:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Security;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

namespace ComputingProjectwh.TestPages._1._Further_Mechanics
{
    public partial class Moments_and_Energy_Test1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsValid)
                return;
            int score = 0;
            List<RadioButtonList> list = new List<RadioButtonList>() { RadioButtonList1, RadioButtonList2, RadioButtonList3, RadioButtonList4, RadioButtonList5, RadioButtonList6, RadioButtonList7, RadioButtonList8, RadioButtonList9, RadioButtonList10 };
            foreach (var element in list)
            {
                if (element.SelectedValue == "Correct")
                {
                    score++;
                }

            }
            Response.Write("you scored: " + score);
            Button1.Visible = false;

            if (score != 0);
            {
                SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb);Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=aspnet-ComputingProjectwh-201‌​70404101246.m‌​df;");

                var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT AspNetUserTestScores (Id, MomentAndEnergyTestScore) VALUES (UserId, score)";
                cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

                sqlConnection1.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlConnection1.Close();


            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have received an enormous variety of errors, most of which were related to an incorrect connection string which is now (I hope) correct. I am currently getting the error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot open database "aspnet-ComputingProjectwh-20170404101246.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'DANS-PC\danie'.
```

Comment: We can't really help with a login failure.  You gotta get that right yourself.

Comment: any idea how i might go about that? @GordonLinoff note that i am using the locally created database